# Função que mostra lista em ordem reversa

Tags: python, lista-encadeada

```
def imprimeDeTrasParaFrente(lista):
    if lista == None :
       return
    imprimeDeTrasParaFrente(lista.proximo)
    print lista,

class Node(object):

   def __init__(self, carga=None, proximo=None):
       self.carga = carga
       self.proximo = proximo

   def __str__(self):
       return str(self.carga)

   no1, no2, no3 = Node(1), Node(2), Node(3)
   no1.proximo, no2.proximo = no2, no3

   imprimeDeTrasParaFrente(no1)
```

Com a função imprimeDeTrasParaFrente() consegui imprimir os elementos da lista em ordem reversa, sendo que ela apenas checa se a lista esta vazia e chama ela mesma com o próximo nó da lista. Na minha perspectiva a função print nunca é chamada por que quando a lista se encontra vazia a função simplesmente retorna e termina o programa, ou estou errado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não há nada de errado com a lógica do seu programa, ele funciona exatamente como você descreveu: exibe os valores contidos nos nós de uma lista encadeada iterando a partir do último nó em direção ao primeiro.

O que está fazendo ele não funcionar é a **indentação** dos blocos, que é algo crucial em `Python`.

Para que tudo funcione perfeitamente, fique atento na indentação do código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Referência [Wikibooks](https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python/Conceitos_b%C3%A1sicos/Indenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

Comment: consegui compreender a logica agora, funcões recursivas chamam elas mesmas dentro da função, o comando return esta encerrando a funcão dentro do propio escopo da função isso quer dizer o fluxo do programa volta para o escopo da função principal então seria possivel adicionar mais um return ao final da função imprimeDeTrasParaFrente() sendo assim funções recursivas podem conter dois return mas ao final retornar apenas um.